# Display angular expressions through binded html code

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm currently working on a Mean stack app and I'm building a reusable table component on my angular side. Currently with "hardcoded" tabes I do the usual that you see in tutorials to display a table.

```
<tr *ngFor="let car of cars">
   <td>{{ car.name }}</td>
   <td>{{ car.make }}</td>
</tr>
```

However in my reusable component, I generate this html into a variable called tdHTML. I'm trying to have tdHTML act the same as the td's from above however when I try the following

```
<tr *ngFor="let car of cars" [innerHTML]="this.tdHTML"></tr>
```

I do not get the expected output. Instead, my table will be populated with the actual text "{{ car.make }}" etc instead of the values binded to these variables.

How do I get the value associted with {{ car.make }} instead of the text using the above method?

P.S using Angular 2 incase that's relevant info. Also unsure if the title is descriptive enough.

Comment: You don't need to refer to "this" object, just use 
 [innerHTML]="tdHTML", that should solve the issue

Comment: @Mr.Wolf should this work even though tdHTML is generated in my typescript file? Why do you not need the this just for future reference?

Comment: "this" is implicit in the html, I don't think you need to specify like that, assuming tdHTML is defined something like tdHTML: string = '<html></html>'; in component.ts file. If you still face issues, then you might have to check how tdHTML is defined

Comment: Are you trying to embed angular HTML, if so, you might want to seach `<ng-content>` topic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent of $compile in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2)

Comment: Also take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular/38888009#38888009